# How to import library with TypeScript Playground

Tags: typescript, typescript-playground

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) does not seem to balk at this import:

```
import * as _ from "underscore";
```

until you try to use it, like:

```
const equalResult = _.isEqual('ABC', '123');
```

Then, it generates the error:

```
[ERR]: Executed JavaScript Failed:
[ERR]: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

The playground seems to understand the library because it gives JSDoc, so I'm thinking that this can work, but how?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I'd recommend not using the TS Playground if you are also having to deal with NPM imports. I'd instead use StackBlitz or CodePen (for example).

Comment: FYI other options are not an answer. TS playground serves a purpose, you don't need a React web app to run 5 lines of code. Simplicity is its main advantage.

Comment: The main point of the TS playground is to reproduce compilation errors or other issues with types, not to actually run code.

Answer (score 19):

TypeScript Playground isn't a fully fledged sandbox solution. It's merely meant as a simple type explorer that doesn't need dependencies.

For your use case I would recommend using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) instead. It comes with a whole bunch of TypeScript templates to choose from when creating a sandbox. TypeScript Playground also has an export menu where you can open your code in CodeSandbox directly.

[image: CodeSandbox export]

The UI is based off of VS Code, so if you're used to that you will feel just at home.

Comment: Code sandbox is for frontend things. We backend devs don't understand that.

Comment: @user14492 No it's not. Here's a backend example with NestJS: https://codesandbox.io/s/w1xru

Answer (score 5):

If by "importing" you mean using `import` to include an npm package that can be accessed at runtime, that is not a feature of the TypeScript Playground, unfortunately; it's intended for testing features of the language and the compiler.

You'll need to use a sandbox environment if you want to include npm packages, bundlers, etc.; checkout [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/), as others have suggested.

---

About your particular error:

> ```
> [ERR]: Executed JavaScript Failed:
> [ERR]: Cannot use import statement outside a module
> ```

This is due to your current configuration, not the lack of package support by TypeScript Playground. By default, your *.js* output probably looks something like this:

```js
import * as _ from "underscore";
const equalResult = _.isEqual('ABC', '123');
```

This is because the default `module` setting in the Playground is set to `ESNext`.

[image: Compiler options]

If we change this to `CommonJS` for example, we get:

```js
"use strict";
var __createBinding = (this && this.__createBinding) || (Object.create ? 

// A bunch more lines .....

const _ = __importStar(require("underscore"));
const equalResult = _.isEqual('ABC', '123');
```

Now we get another error that tells us explicitly that our package is unavailable:

```
[ERR]: "Executed JavaScript Failed:" 
[ERR]: Check dependency list! Synchronous require cannot resolve module 'underscore'. 
       This is the first mention of this module!
```

While the playground is smart enough to auto-import the types for `import` statements, it doesn't support external modules outside of this.

Answer (score 2):

I came here trying to solve that same problem, and then continued digging, and this was the best solution I came up with:

If you go to https://jsfiddle.net/, you can select "Typescript" as your language and "underscore.js" as your library and it should create a similar environment to the playground. The language and library can be selected by clicking the language type above the JS text box in the JFiddle website.

Doesn't answer your original question, but may be a viable work around for someone.